# Proving Undecidability with reductions - Why do some proofs not use an Oracle?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, automata, reductions, undecidability

I'm specifically referring to this group of questions here: [https://www.cs.rice.edu/~nakhleh/COMP481/final_review_sp06_sol.pdf](https://www.cs.rice.edu/%7Enakhleh/COMP481/final_review_sp06_sol.pdf)

So as I've learnt it, say we want to prove a new Language L is undecidable using a known undecidable language D, we use Oracle calls to L to solve an instance of D right?

In none of these questions is an oracle used - For example, with L9 :"M' on input w: it
runs M on x and accepts if M halts on x" That's the algorithm; no oracle is used. I understand the reasoning to their solutions, but shouldn't they be using an oracle call? I'm very new to this so sorry if I'm misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

An oracle call is stronger than emulating a TM: it allows you in constant time to solve the task of checking if some $x$ is in the language specified by the oracle.

What you saw didn't use oracle machines, since it proved by assuming towards contradiction: It assumed there is a machine $M$, and showed how to use its code in order to build a new machine $M'$ solving a problem that can't be solved - hence $M$ doesn't exist.

Comment: So what is the correct way of doing it for proving undecidability of languages? With or without the calls, or do they both work? And thanks for the help

Comment: Both ways work. Whatever you prefer and feel is more natural to you would work

Comment: Also, any proof using oracles can be converted to a proof without them, and vice versa

Comment: What is the type of method called for this approach? I know my version is a reduction, but what is this way known as?

Comment: Proving by contradiction. Its a general concept not used only in computer science.

Comment: Oh yeah I know that, I just don't understand how they can just say 'accepts if M halts on x', isn't that kind of undecidable in itself?

Comment: You assumed we have the code of $M$. Then run it, until it stops (if it stops). When it does so, your original TM $M'$ will accept

Comment: I see - Just to check then, where is the essence of contradictions in these proofs?

Comment: The essence of contradictions is that we create a machine to decide a language we already know is undecidable.

Comment: Thanks again! Just to confirm, is the method being used in these questions a 'many to one reduction' whereas the method I'm talking about is a 'turning reduction'? Is this the correct name for the two?